# Rails gem for token authentication of outside data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, twitter

I'll describe my question through my use case -- I (using the tweetstream gem) receive and process tweets on a push basis, and for some of those events, I reply to the user with a link to a signup form for my website. Currently, users have to do auth via twitter on my site before they can submit the sign up form so that I can securely verify that they own that twitter account they claim to be.

However, that is preventing a lot of conversion, so I would like to remove the login with twitter step. My thought then, was that on receiving an event, I could hash their twitter user_id with a random string I store, and add that hash (token) as a query param on the signup link. The link would autofill the token into a hidden field in the signup form, thus (I think?) allowing us to verify the user's twitter id again on form submission.

The one caveat to this is someone could use another user's signup link and appear as them, but this isn't a concern in our case because due to the nature of the signup data. Doing that maliciously wouldn't make sense, and doing it unintentionally, we can do by displaying the apparent twitter handle prominently on the form. Account access post signup will still require login with twitter so that isn't an issue either.

So my question then is, does this seem like a sound approach, and are there any rails gems that have this functionality or would be useful? (Basically a custom version of how authenticity token protection works I think) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is not having a signup form and instead simply letting people login using twitter. Is there really something you need them to manually fill in on the signup forum that you can't automatically retrieve when they login with twitter?

Comment: Then assume everything from twitter and have the form only ask for credit info.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by assume -- basically my issue is I need to have their twitter id in the form submission somehow, currently I grab serverside from twitter auth, but making them log in with twitter is stopping a lot of people. Likewise if I just put their id in plaintext in the signup link url, they could modify it and send an invalid id or one that's not their own. I'm basically trying to associate their CC with their twitter id for reuse later without additional re-entry